# How to use Data Annotation validation with C# fields and not properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have my model with C# fields and that is decorated with some field level attributes of other library. 
When I add validation such as [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false)] to those field, it is not validated.

It is only working for properties, however I could not switch it to properties. 
Hence can some one let me know, how to validate C# fields with Data annotation validator.

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: I think it can only be applied to properties, not fields: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664638(v=pandp.50).aspx

Comment: @Jacob Thanks for your reference. I will workout custom properties to acheive it. Thanks.

Comment: You can't (its not supported). And it would be pointless anyway since the `DefaultModelBinder` will not bind posted values to fields anyway